# How many samples from a poisson distribution until you have X unique values?

Tags: statistics

Suppose you have a population of non-negative integers normally distributed with a mean of 0 standard deviation of a large value (say around 1 Million).

Is there a formula that tells you how many samples you would expect to take before you had seen X unique values (let's say X might be somewhere around 12 Million)?

(The distribution only needs to be approximately normal, other distributions, like the poisson distribution will answer my question just as well).

Comment: There is an important distinction between a continuous and a discrete distribution when looking for unique values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go with Poisson, since it satisfies all your requirements if the rate parameter is large enough.

In general, let $N_i\sim Poi(\lambda)$ and $P(n_i)$ be the probability that $N_i=n_i$.

Now, let $U_k$ be the number of unique values after $k$ draws. In this case, $U_k=|\cup_{j=1}^k\{n_j\}|$. With this notation, we can define $X(u):=\{\min k:U_k=u\}$, which is the number of draws until you first see $u$ unique values.

You want a formula for $E[X(u)]$, presumably as a function of $u$ with $\lambda$ held fixed.

This is a *first hitting time* problem from the field of stochastic processes, where $U_k$ is our stochastic process, and $k$ is the "time" index. Specifically, it is a discrete-time [pure birth process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process), with state-dependent birth probabilities $b_n=P(U_{k+1}=n+1|U_k=n)$.

Therefore, this process satisfies the [Markov property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property), which implies that once we specify $b_n$ for $n\in [1...u-1]$, where $k=u$ is an absorbing state $b_u=0$, we can answer any question we want about this process. Of course, how do we calculate the $b_n$?

We know: $b_0=1$ and $b_u=0$, and the probabilities for states in-between will monotonically decrease towards $0$. Lets try to get $b_1$:

After the first time step, we will have chosen a value for $N_1$, so we know that we must choose a value that is NOT $N_1$:

$b_1=P(N_2\neq N_1)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}P(N_1=j)(1-P(j))=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\lambda}\lambda^j}{j!}(1-\frac{e^{\lambda}\lambda^j}{j!}) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left\{\frac{e^{\lambda}\lambda^j}{j!}-\frac{e^{2\lambda}\lambda^{2j}}{j!^2}\right\}$

Not a pretty sum...and it gets worse for $n>1$. So unfortunately, there will not be a nice formula for your problem.